# Using a dictionary to translate a string

Tags: python, dictionary, translate

I'm trying to use a function to translate a string using a dictionary, and append the translated words into a string to form an interlinear translation.

However, whenever it comes to appending the translated words to the string, it sees the direction to the key as a string itself.

Here's the code:

A little forewarning, I have an odd sense of humor and let that shine in my #comments.

```
#imperts--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#I have no clue what any of this means
from lexicon import lexicon

#Define Isopsephy ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#alpha AND numeric?!
#from isopsephy import isopsephy

#cold-barrel test___________________________________________________________________________________
#what are we reading from anyway?
john_1_1_greek = 'Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ Λόγος, καὶ ὁ Λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν Θεόν καὶ Θεὸς ἦν ὁ Λόγος.'
john_1_1_english = []

#Translate function---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def translate():
    for word in john_1_1_greek.split(" "):
        if word in lexicon.items():
            john_1_1_english.append(lexicon[word['English']])
        return word

#run the function-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

translate()

#john1_1_isopsephy = []


#test print
print(john_1_1_greek)
print(john_1_1_english)
```

Whenever I just did ".append(lexicon[word])", it actually appendended the entire value, which includes the pronunciation, english translation, etc.

For instance:

```
'Ἐν': {
        'word': 'Ἐν',
        'pronunciation': 'En',
        'English': 'In [the]'},
```

However, when I try to point it directly to ".append(lexicon[word['English'], I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\turds\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 23, in 
translate()
File "C:\Users\turds\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 18, in translate
john_1_1_english.append(lexicon[word['English']])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Instead of `lexicon[word['English']]` use `lexicon[word]['English']`

Comment: side note: the text is not modern greek, your translator may or may not understand it.

Comment: *side note: the text is not modern greek, your translator may or may not understand it*  Yes, the module I'm importing has my custom dictionary there, where it's Koine.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access the '`English`' key of a string object, which is not possible since strings can only be indexed by integers.

You need to first look up the dictionary value for the current word.

Check if the current word is in the dictionary using if word in lexicon. If it is, we look up the value of the current word in the dictionary using `lexicon[word]`

Here's a version of code that should work :

```
#imports
from lexicon import lexicon

#cold-barrel test
john_1_1_greek = 'Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ Λόγος, καὶ ὁ Λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν Θεόν καὶ Θεὸς ἦν ὁ Λόγος.'
john_1_1_english = []

#Translate function
def translate():
    for word in john_1_1_greek.split(" "):
        if word in lexicon:
            english_translation = lexicon[word]['English']
            john_1_1_english.append(english_translation)

#run the function
translate()

#test print
print(john_1_1_greek)
print(john_1_1_english)
```

Comment: Excellent show, old man.  This certainly got it working, but now I'm at a point where I'm stuck knowing "It did exactly what I asked it to do, but not at all what I want it to do."

Here's my output:

Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ Λόγος, καὶ ὁ Λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν Θεόν καὶ Θεὸς ἦν ὁ Λόγος.
['In [the]', 'beginning', 'the', 'and', 'the', 'word', 'with', 'God', 'and', 'the']

I want it to flow 1:1 with the wording of the Greek.

Thank you again, very much, for your assistance btw.  You guys are great.